# restart emulator behavior in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-debugging

I have a question about the expected behavior of Window Phone 7.5 emulator.

If I ***deactivate*** (*start button*), ***close*** (*back button* from first screen) or ***tombstone*** my data (selecting this option in VS first and then in the emulator clicking *start button*), and then press Stop Debugging (Shift+F5) in VS, all changed data in my app for that session is retained when I start the debug process again (F5).

However, when I just changed data in my app in the emulator and don't actively deactivate, close or tombstone my app, and then press Stop Debugging (Shift+F5) and then Start Debugging (F5) the changed data is not retained. I've noticed that upon stopping debugging, neither the `Application_Deactivated` or `Application_Closing` occur as well.

Is this expected behavior when starting/stopping the debugging processes? I'm asking because I need to know if this has any effect in the real world, like for example if I'm in my app and make a change and then someone turns off the phone completely right then and there and turns it back on, will my data be retained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. What you are doing is effectively crashing your app. If the phone/app is shut down in a normal situation then Deactivated or Closing will be invoked.

Comment: Oh, what a relief. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Not a problem :) It makes things really hard if you don't know whether you can rely on certain behaviour.